# Notification not come when app is killed in vivo

Tags: xamarin.android

I have implemented the notification code in xamarin android. I tested this code on Samsung device using  android version Pie works fine,this works fine.However when 
I tested on Vivo the notification does not come up when the app is killed and android version is (Pie on both).

Comment: You need to show us the code, using the code tags, or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Please check code above

Answer (score 0):

Chinese ROMs using (Oxygen OS, MIUI etc) when the apps are swiped from the recent app tray your app gets terminated ( similar to Force Stop). And due to this every task running in the background like Services, Jobs gets killed with the app. Even High priority FCM doesn’t see the daylight in Chinese ROMs

So user needs to enable auto start in settings for app to keep background service/Job running.By default it is off.To do this in some of the devices we can use,

try this:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{  
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        string manufacturer = Android.OS.Build.Manufacturer;
        switch (manufacturer)
        {
            case "xiaomi":
                intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter",
                        "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
                break;
            case "oppo":
                intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                        "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));

                break;
            case "vivo":
                intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager",
                        "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
                break;
        }

        IList<ResolveInfo> arrayList = PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);

        if (arrayList.Count> 0)
        {
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

more info you could refer to [Enable background services and Jobs (or FCM) in Chinese ROMs](https://medium.com/mindorks/enable-background-services-in-chinese-roms-32e73dfba1a6)